# When would you put a semicolon after a method closing brace?

Tags: java, syntax

I've been programming in Java for a while, and I've just come across this syntax for the first time:

```
public Object getSomething(){return something;};
```

What's interesting me is the final semicolon. It doesn't seem to be causing a compiler error, and as far as I know isn't generating runtime errors, so it seems to be valid syntax. When would I use this syntax? Or is it just something that is allowed but generally not used?

Comment: note: the same applies to classes - you can terminate them with `;` in `C++`-style; comes in handy when using directly ported code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's allowed by the grammar as a concession to harmless syntax errors, but it's not generally used and doesn't mean anything different (than leaving the semicolon out).

Just as a `};` *inside* a method (such as after an `if` block) is a null statement and is allowed, an errant semicolon *outside* a method is considered a null declaration and is allowed.

Specifically, the following production from the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/syntax.doc.html) allows this:

> ```
> ClassBodyDeclaration:
>   ; 
>   [static] Block
>   ModifiersOpt MemberDecl
> ```

Answer (score 11):

It's simply an empty statement - it is most likely a typo.

Consider the fact that in all C-based languages, a statement is terminated with a semicolon.  A hanging semicolon like this simply terminates the current statement which in this case is nothing.

Comment: So I could technically add any number of semicolons anywhere other than the middle of a statement?

Comment: @froadie - Yes, you could do that.

Answer (score 9):

> *Or is it just something that is allowed but generally not used?*

Yeap, that's it. It is valid Java but doesn't do anything:

```
public class X  {
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ;;;;;
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon is interpreted as an empty statement, which is permissible whereever a statement is permissible.

```
EmptyStatement:
 ;
```

As Java specification says

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6