# Difference between two method implementations?

Tags: java, syntax

Is there any difference in between the two method definitions below? Eclipse does not complain for any of them.

```
private void method1() {
}
```

and

```
private void method2() {    
};
```

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724371/when-would-you-put-a-semicolon-after-a-method-closing-brace

Semicolon is allowed by the grammar, but is not necesarry here and isn't used by most people in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semicolon is not part of the method so there is no difference between the method definitions.

The semicolon is just part of the class body.

```
class AClass {
    private void method() { }

    ;
}
```

This is equivalent.

You can put initializer statements in the class body. They are executed when an instance is created. A single semicolon constitutes an empty statement so it is not very useful. Other initializers are more useful:

```
class AClass {
    private void method() { }

    ;

    int x = 5;

    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

    int y = 5; ; ;
}
```

Comment: What kind of code formating is this?

Comment: Standard? Well... most of the time. The empty statements are useless so I didn't put them on a new line just to demonstrate that they have no effect. But except for that: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141270.html#18761

Comment: You are correct. I looks so very odd :)

Answer (score 6):

The `;` does not help and hurt. It does not belong to `method2()` and will be ignored by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any semicolon after the closing braces of the method.

But if you do put it, the compiler will just consider it as an empty statement and hence it is not giving your any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactic sugar.

(you can always run `javap` to make sure the bytecodes are the same)