# Why don't we use semicolon at the end of class in java?

Tags: java

```
class AddMain {
    int a, b;

    public static void main(String ar[]){
        System.out.println(a + b);
    }
}
```

This is simple java program and my question is why we don't use semicolon at the end of the class braces. Please let me know and thanks to all.

Comment: Because that's the language.

Comment: Because the syntax has been defined as such.

Comment: socket is because they are also a java programmer and i want to know the reason of that semi colon

Comment: one more question is why java.lang  package is auto imported in java

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724371/when-would-you-put-a-semicolon-after-a-method-closing-brace

Comment: This is not so bad question and because there are languages without semicolon, it makes sense to ask why we need it in Java.

Comment: @vefthym huh? We don't need semicolon in Java?

Comment: It is the java designers' decision of syntax.

Comment: Please try to be nice when commenting. I don't see anything wrong with this question. As a brief answer, C++ has a semicolon since you can declare an *instance* of that class at the end of the declaration. That makes little sense in Java where you can only have *references* to classes. So a semicolon would be superfluous.

Comment: can you explain it more ?

Comment: Not until the question is reopened. If you can, try to improve it. Questions consisting of a title and code tend to rub folk up the wrong way.

Comment: Why don't you use `;` at the end of `if(){}` or `for(){}` or `while(){}` ??? Its for the same reason... When you have a block of statements inside `{}`, a `;` is not required...

Comment: i don't know the reason so i am asking about this  please ans me and please let me know why java.lang package is automatically imported thanks

Comment: @user2894408 I suggest that you do the following: 1. Edit the question, so that it can be re-opened. See instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Bathsheba or anyone else cannot add a new answer, until you do that 2. Ask a new question, or search other posts for why java.lang is automatically imported. You should not have two different (irrelevant) questions in the same post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semicolon in Java is a separator - it separates statements. But if you put some statements into a block of code using `{ ... a block of code ...}`, then this separator is not needed, because the `{}` brackets do the separation themselves.

Have a look at an article like this one http://beginwithjava.blogspot.cz/2008/06/those-pesky-semicolons.html

Comment: why java.lang package is auto imported

Comment: @user2894408 please add this as a new question